# Can I block/disable scrolling above a div?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have this page with a start div. I use this code:

```
$(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('html, body')
      .css({
        'overflow': 'auto'
      })
      .animate({
        scrollTop: $('.myDiv').offset().top
      }, 2000);
    }, 2000);
    return false;
  });
```

to scroll down to the .myDiv after page load and a timeout.
Is their any way to block/disable scrolling above myDiv? So that you cannot scroll up to the startpage.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: how about using some sort of javascript so that when start div is not on the browser that its CSS is changed to `display:none;` so it's hidden that way?

Comment: Yes, but when i do that - the page scroll down to the middle of .myDiv? Can i solve that?

Comment: take the height value via javascript just before setting  the `display:none;`, and set that as a margin-top or padding-top to your `.myDiv`

Comment: I'm not that good at javascript - can you edit this jsfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/em9yycj5/9/

Comment: to be honest, Chanckjh's answer does it better than my comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/xdba4w3k/1/

HTML

```
<div class="start"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Jquery

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 500) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 500
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you - it is working, but is it possible to do this more smooth? or will i have to make in some other way then? :-)